# File algorithms.sty not found

Tags: packages, algorithms

I'm getting an error while compile my tex studio

The error is:

> File `algorithms.sty' not found. \usepackage

My code is:

```
\immediate\write18{makeindex \jobname.nlo -s nomencl.ist -o \jobname.nls}
\documentclass{cls-TA}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{glossaries}
\usepackage{algorithms}
\usepackage[nonend]{algpseudocode}
\makeatletter
\def\BState{\State\hskip-\ALG@thistlm}
\makeatotherkage
%\usepackage[top=4cm,right=3cm,bottom=3cm,left=4cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{a4paper,total={210mm,297mm},top=40mm,right=30mm,bottom=30mm,left=40mm}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedright\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{R}[1]{>{\raggedleft\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}
\usepackage{tabularx,ragged2e,booktabs,caption}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\parindent=1.05cm
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage[table,xcdraw]{xcolor}
%code untuk halaman di samping kanan bawah
\usepackage{scrpage2}
\ifoot[]{}
\cfoot[]{}
\ofoot[\pagemark]{\pagemark}

\pagestyle{scrplain}

\begin{document}
    \input{Info}
    \HalamanJudul
    \HalamanPengesahan
%   \input{Persembahan}
    \input{Pernyataan}
    \input{Abstrak}
        \input{Abstract}
    \input{KataPengantar}
    \DaftarIsi
    \DaftarGambar            % jika ada gambar
    \DaftarTabel             % jika ada tabel

    \MulaiIsiDisertasi % ini harus ditulis sebelum Bab I
\input{Bab1}
\input{Bab2}
\input{Bab3}
\input{Bab4}
\input{Bab5}
\input{BAB6}
% ........ dst

\clearpage
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{DAFTAR PUSTAKA}
%\renewcommand{\IEEEtranand}{dan}
\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}
\bibliography{ReferensiTA}

%\renewcommand{\harvardand}{dan}

%\newpage
%\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{LAMPIRAN}
%\ \vspace{0.45\textheight}
%\begin{center}
%   {\Large LAMPIRAN}
%\end{center}
%\part{LAMPIRAN}
%\input{lampiran}

\end{document}
```

If you wanted me to install package of algorithms.sty, i already instaled it from my package manager
[image: Text]

i also checked my texstudio have been read the package
[image: Text]

Comment: That is normal:  you have the MiKTeX package  `algorithms` installed,  but it contains the  `algorithm.sty` file – without a final `s`.

Comment: @Bernard It's still same, either with s or whithout s

Comment: Just in case: refresh the filenames database with MiKTeX console.